# Prove the inequality with simple concepts

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Given $3abc=2(a+b+c)$
Prove that $8(ab+bc+ca) \leq 5a^2b^2c^2+8 \leq 5(a^2+b^2+c^2)+18$
How to procees
Can anyone give any hints

Comment: Are there any assumptions about $a$, $b$, $c$?

Comment: $a,b,c$ are positive

Answer (score 3):

After homogenization the both inequalities are equivalent to
$\sum\limits_{cyc}(5a^3-3a^2b-3a^2c+abc)\geq0$, which is obvious.

Comment: Why is that obvious? Do you mean the inequality can be proved term by term in the sum?

Comment: @David because $\sum\limits_{cyc}(5a^3-3a^2b-3a^2c+abc)=5\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc)+2\sum\limits_{cyc}c(a-b)^2\geq0$, which is true by Schur.

Comment: Okay, good answer.